# My Shell sort doesnt work as intended and i need some help figuring out what iam doing wrong

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I got a shell sort program done in Java using `ArrayList`s. Somehow the output is not as intended. Could I please have some help as to what I'm doing wrong. With examples if possible.

```
int inner, outer, temp;
int interval = 1;

while (interval > 0) {
    for (outer = interval; outer < sortmaxlength; outer++) {
        temp = shelllist.get(outer);

        inner = outer;

        while (inner > interval - 1 && shelllist.get(inner - interval) >= temp) {
            shelllist.set(inner,(inner - interval));
            inner -= interval;
        }
        shelllist.set(inner,temp);
    }

    interval = (interval - 1) / 3;
}

for (int j = 0; j < shelllist.size(); j++){
    jTextArea2.append(Integer.toString(shelllist.get(j)));
    jTextArea2.append(",");
}
```

Comment: Please show the data you have, how it is converted and how you want it. You are telling us your code doesn't work, so thats not a good resource te determine what you want.

Comment: *Could I please have some help as to what I'm doing wrong*  Certainly.  System.out.println.  Put a println statement after every line of your code.  See what your variables are doing while the code runs.  When you see a wrong result reported by a println, you'll know which line of your code is incorrect.  This is the only way to learn how to solve your own logic problems.